# nodemon app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting ... Error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-modules, nodemon, nodejs-server

**appjs**

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const homeRouter = require("./routes/home.routes");

const app = express();
const port = 8000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "assets")));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "images")));

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", "views");

app.use("/", homeRouter);

app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`server listen on port ${port}`);
});
```

**home routes**

```
const router = require('express').Router()

const homeController = require('../controllers/home.controller')

router.get('/', homeController.getHome)

module.exports = router
```

**homecontroller**

```
const productsModel = require('../models/products.models')

exports.getHome = (req,res,next) => {
    //get products
    //get render index.ejs
    productsModel.getAllproducts().then(products => {
        res.render('index', {
            products: products
        })
    })

}
```

**products.models**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const DB_URL = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/shop'

const productsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
name:String,
image:String,
price:String,
category:String,
description:String
})

const product = mongoose.model('product', productsSchema)

exports.getAllproducts = () => {
    //connect to db
    //get products
    //disconnect
return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    mongoose.connect(DB_URL).then(() => {
        return product.find({})
    
    }).then(products => {
        mongoose.disconnect()
        resolve(products)
    }).catch(err => reject(err))
})
}
```

**Error**

> node:events:504
> throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
> ^
>
> Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8000
> at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1330:16)
> at listenInCluster (node:net:1378:12)
> at Server.listen (node:net:1465:7)
> at Function.listen (C:\Users\islam\OneDrive\Desktop\shopnode\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:635:24)
> at Object. (C:\Users\islam\OneDrive\Desktop\shopnode\app.js:17:5)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1157:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12) Emitted 'error' event on Server
> instance at:
> at emitErrorNT (node:net:1357:8)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {   code: 'EADDRINUSE',
> errno: -4091,   syscall: 'listen',   address: '::',   port: 8000 }
> [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Answer (score 0):

In case we have some project running are both same port and on your server then catch this error and i have solve in that time.

1. open terminal set your Dir location and run this command on your terminal
   doing this things
   using this command :- `pkill node`
   or
   for mac :-  `sudo killall -9 node`
   or
   for windows :- > `killall -9 node`
   or

   `killall node`
2. otherwise use this on your defined port modify your code
   `var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;`

do all this things then server restart
`npm start` or `node app.js`